# set domain to a ubuntu 20.04 vps with bind

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, vps, ubuntu-20.04

so I have a ubuntu 20.04 vps and a website running on it, I wanted to point my domain to it. but `nslookup railnet.ir` gives `** server can't find railnet.ir: SERVFAIL` 
the vps ip is `87.236.210.159` and the domain is `railnet.ir`
the thing I did:
`apt install bind9`
and then the configs: `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    allow-query { any; };
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
    dnssec-validation auto;
    listen-on{
        87.236.210.159;
    };
    listen-on-v6 { none;};
};
```

and `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "railnet.ir" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.railnet.ir";
        allow-transfer { 87.236.210.159; };
        also-notify { 87.236.210.159; };
};
```

and eventually `/etc/bind/db.railnet.ir`:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.railnet.ir. myemail.gmail.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.railnet.ir.
@       IN      A       87.236.210.159
```

and also in my domain provider website I did set `server name` to `ns1.railnet.ir` and `ip address` to `87.236.210.159`

this is my first time doing such thing, so obviously I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure it out

Comment: As a sidenote: do use short TTL for all fields before you *know* your setup is working. I'd suggest 60 seconds for now, and extend it to an hour or a day once you know it works. 7 days is excessive in most cases; what if you're forced to change IP? That's up to seven days before everyone's onboard with your new IPs.

Comment: @vidarlo thanks!   a question, you said it's better to host dns externally like cloudflare instead of hosting them yourself, does it really matter if i plan that like only 4~10 people are going to use my site? I mean in this case, does it have any real downside to host it myself?

Comment: The risk is basically downtime. I believe DNS is free with CF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to define `ns1.railnet.ir.` in your zone. Add a line

`ns1 IN A 87.236.210.159`

Second, your DNS server does not reply. `dig railnet.ir @87.236.210.159` does not return any answers. To figure out why, have a look at the logs provided by bind. Likely it can't open the zone file for some reason, or finds it invalid.

Third, your `also-notify` and `allow-transfer` points back to yourself based on what you write. Commonly these should point at your secondary DNS servers for that domain.

Start by making bind reply authoratively for all valid names, e.g.

- `dig railnet.ir SOA @87.236.210.159` should return `ns1.railnet.ir`
- `dig ns1.railnet.ir A @87.236.210.159` should return `87.236.210.159`

When that's done, update whois, and hopefully glue records will be configured correctly.

In addition, you probably want to define some ACL's. As it is now, bind answers everything anyone bothers to ask. You probably want it to answer to zones it controls, and deny other queries.

In addition, DNS is one of those things that's a bit finicky to host yourself. Not impossible, but with only one domain you have to rely on glue records. Together with caching, this can lead to short downtime being cached. It's often a better approach to host DNS externally, with e.g. Cloudflare.